# Can I use Wago 221 and 2273 connectors outdoors?

Tags: electrical

Are Wago connectors of the type 221 and 2273 safe to use outdoors where there will be a summer/winter heat cycle of say -10 to +30 degrees Celsius?

Also how do the Wago connectors hold up against oxidation of the copper wire? in the long term?

Comment: They should be in a weather proof junction box. I have used them to splice low voltage "communications" wires and they have held up in the Pacific North West maybe 3 years so far.

Comment: Sorry i should have made it clear they are in up to code junction box.

Comment: The fundamental rule (110.3B) is that everything must be used according to its instructions and labeling.  So go get the connector's data sheet.  Either it is labeled for outdoor use (in wet locations)... or it's not.  That is because when the product was (UL) *listed*, it was only evaluated for those uses.  (by contrast, suppose you want to splice a fuel-pump supply connection inside an industrial fuel tank, well, UL didn't *test* for that, so nobody knows what will happen!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wagobox capsule junction box for those connectors is IP68 rated - waterproof to 4m. Not sure if it is UL listed or allowed in US codes though.

However, those connectors should be ok in any junction box rated for exterior use..

Comment: Wago sells an antioxidant grease in a convenient syringe for injecting into the connector. This should prevent any oxidation. Don't use just any grease as some greases will degrade plastic. It could well be that the silicone electrical socket grease sold in small foil packets at auto parts stores could also be applied to the wire before inserting.

Comment: @JimStewart Do you know the name or model number of Wago's antioxidant grease product? Having trouble finding it online...

Comment: I found it once and now can't find my reference, but here is one product: https://www.etrailer.com/Accessories-and-Parts/LubriMatic/11755.html

Comment: Here is the Wago product  which they say allows use with solid aluminium conductor of certain sizes: http://global.wago.com/en/services/standards-regulations/terminating-aluminum-conductors/index.jsp